# How to check download status using response code after click on download link using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to handle/check whether file is downloaded success or not using response status/Code (200 is success and other than 200 failure)?
I know we can check file is downloaded success or not using 'File Exists' in a downloaded folder location which we specified. But in my requirement,file size is more than 8 GB hence i wanted to check file download status using http/https response code because we want to retry for download in case of any failure happened while downloading. 
It would be really helpful if anyone share the solution for this.

Comment: Maybe jou can extract the link with selenium and download it with http client?

Comment: I don't think it can be done using response codes (not that I'm aware of). The easiest way I could think to check that the download is in progress within the browser would be to add in a step to open the downloads pane address("chrome://downloads/" or "about:downloads" for firefox) and then just validate that the file is showing there with a progress bar